# Linq group by groups

Tags: c#, linq

i had this question at the interview process, having following list

```
Tom 1000
Mark 2200
Antony 3000
Paul 2500
Kris 2800
Ron 3110
```

write linq query using group by to get groups of people with number in between

```
0-1500
1501-2500
2501-4000
```

How can it be done ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int?[] ranges = new int?[] { 1500, 2500, 4000 };
var groups = from p in people
             group p by ranges.FirstOrDefault(r => r > p.Value) into g
             where g.Key != null
             select new {
                 People = g,
                 To = g.Key,
                 From = ranges.Where(r => r < g.Key)
                              .Select(r => r + 1).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Last()
             };
```

Sample data:

```
var people = new List<Person>
{
    new Person { Name = "Tom", Value = 1000 },
    new Person { Name = "Mark", Value = 2200 },
    new Person { Name = "Antony", Value = 3000 },
    new Person { Name = "Paul", Value = 2500 },
    new Person { Name = "Kris", Value = 2800 },   
    new Person { Name = "Kris", Value = 5800 },
};
```

Output:

```
0-1500
1000: Tom

1501-2500
2200: Mark

2501-4000
3000: Antony
2500: Paul
2800: Kris
```

---

Of course, if you want your code to look better, you can create some Range class. E.g. following query will return ranges with people which fit in range:

```
var ranges = new List<Range<int>> { 0.To(1500), 1501.To(2500), 2501.To(4000) };
var groups = from r in ranges
             select new {
                 Range = r,
                 People = people.Where(p => r.Contains(p.Value))
             };
```

Generic range class:

```
public class Range<T>
    where T : IComparable
{
    public Range(T from, T to)
    {
        if (from.CompareTo(to) > 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("From should not be greater than To");

        From = from;
        To = to;
    }

    public T From { get; private set; }
    public T To { get; private set; }

    public bool Contains(T value)
    {
        return value.CompareTo(From) >= 0 && value.CompareTo(To) <= 0;
    }
}
```

And extension which allow to write code like `0.To(100)` to create ranges from any comparable type:

```
public static Range<T> To<T>(this T from, T to)
    where T: IComparable
{
    return new Range<T>(from, to);
}
```

Comment: Currently your items not found and items in the first group are in the same bucket.

Comment: thanks, anyway what is wrong with this question that it got so many down votes ?

Comment: @kosnkov I didn't downvote, but you always should show what you have tried

Comment: @kosnkov "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)"

Comment: @Servy hold on, I'll check

Comment: @kosnkov +1 for Servy. The question is "I have an interview question, can you do it for me please?". Stack Overflow is not for doing homework assignments.

Comment: To be fair - the question is "I had this interview question and have no idea how to do it - can someone show me?"  Unless they're asking this question _during the interview_ I see no harm in providing a solution as a learning exercise.

Comment: @DStanley It doesn't matter whether it's an interview question, a homework question, a question for a project at their job, an idle curiosity, or what, the OP should still make an attempt to solve the problem, demonstrate what they've tried, show the research that they've done, and explain what problems they have had with their implementation.  SO is not a place to just dump requirements and get completed programs out.

Comment: @kosnkov I updated answer - now it even returns range with `From` and `To` values

Comment: @downvoter, can you explain why you have downvoted working answer?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `GroupBy` on `List.FindIndex`:

```
var ranges = new[]{
    new{ Start=0, End=1500 },  new{ Start=1501, End=2500}, new{ Start=2501, End=4000}
}.ToList();
var players = new[]{
    new{ Name = "Tom", Score = 1000 },
    new{ Name = "Mark", Score = 2200 },
    new{ Name = "Antony", Score = 3000 },
    new{ Name = "Paul", Score = 2500 },
    new{ Name = "Kris", Score = 2800 },
    new{ Name = "Ron", Score = 3110 },
};

var scoreGroups = players.
    GroupBy(p => ranges.FindIndex(r => p.Score >= r.Start && p.Score <= r.End));

foreach (var scoreGroup in scoreGroups)
    Console.WriteLine("Range: {0} <--> {1} Players: {2}"
        , ranges[scoreGroup.Key].Start
        , ranges[scoreGroup.Key].End
        , string.Join(", ", scoreGroup.Select(p => p.Name));
```

Result:

```
Range: 0    <--> 1500 Players: Tom 
Range: 1501 <--> 2500 Players: Mark, Paul
Range: 2501 <--> 4000 Players: Antony, Kris, Ron
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list.GroupBy(g => PickGroup(g));

private string PickGroup(int val)
{
   //some logic to determine which group the input falls into
   //Check the value against the boundaries of the groups  
}
```

Try the above approach

Define the groups based on your ranges and return the string representing the range (0-1500) etc

Comment: I think the "some logic" is what the OP is trying to determine...

Comment: You are nice to answer such questions. @DStanley: OP now has the `GroupBy` API if he didn't know. We aren't here to do coding homework. BTW: you don't need to create a new function to wrap PickGroup, that's wasted memory. Why not `list.GroupBy(PickGroup)`?

Comment: @jods If you don't want to answer the question because you feel you'd be doing someone's work form them then *don't answer the question*.  But giving a poor quality or incomplete answer that doesn't actually help is not appropriate.  If you want to give a bit of information without fully answering the question, i.e. to mention `GroupBy` without giving a full answer, then a comment would be appropriate.

Comment: @Servy agreed, a comment would have been more appropriate.

Comment: The wording of the question suggest that the OP was having difficulty with the LINQ part, so I addressed that accordingly

Answer (score 0):

This's another way:

```
    var people = new List<Tuple<int, string>> { new Tuple<int,string>(1000, "Tom"),
        new Tuple<int,string>(2200, "Mark"),
        new Tuple<int,string>(3000, "Antony"),
        new Tuple<int,string>(2500, "Paul"),
        new Tuple<int,string>(2800, "Kris"),
        new Tuple<int,string>(3110, "Ron"),
    };

    var ranges = new List<Tuple<int, int>> { new Tuple<int,int>(0,1500),
        new Tuple<int,int>(1501,2500),
        new Tuple<int,int>(2501,4000),

    };

    var result = people.GroupBy(person => ranges.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Item1 < person.Item1 && e.Item2 >= person.Item1),
                                (key, g) => new { Range = key, People = g.Select(k => k.Item2) })
```

OUPUT

0-1500  TOM

1501-2500 MARK, PAUL

2501-4000 ANTHONY, KRIS, RON